# Center image within it's container

Tags: css, margin, text-align

I can't seem to center my image, it's positioned absolute to it's parent which is relative.

I've used inspect element to try many ways, but it doesn't seem to want to work.

Please see the example here: http://dassiedev.dassieartisan.com/furniture

Here's my CSS:

```
    .tm-switch-image-container {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 276px;
}
.tm-switch-image-container img {
    width: 276px;
    height: 276px;
    max-width: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To center an `img` within a `div`, give the `img` a `display: inline-block` rule, and then give the `div` a `text-align: center` rule. This will center it horizontally.

```
.tm-switch-image-container {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 276px;
    text-align: center;
}

.tm-switch-image-container img {
    width: 276px;
    height: 276px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: This didn't quite get the results the OP was looking for (at least I believe so).  You have to additionally remove the width and height styling on `.tm-switch-image-container img` for the furniture to show up centered.

Comment: @JasonKlas If the image is only being centered horizontally, and the container is wider than 276px, then this should work.

Comment: "and the container is wider than 276px" that explains it, thank you!  My monitor can't fit 3 of the images horizontally without shrinking them.